# Make uisegmentcontrol a synonym of UISegmentedControl

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

While posting a question regarding the [uisegmentedcontrol](/questions/tagged/uisegmentedcontrol), I noticed that the first suggestion for the tag was actually [uisegmentcontrol](/questions/tagged/uisegmentcontrol), which is an incorrect spelling of the UI element.

The [uisegmentcontrol](/questions/tagged/uisegmentcontrol) and the [uisegmentedcontrol](/questions/tagged/uisegmentedcontrol) tags should at the very least be synonyms, if not completely merged, as they are the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, makes sense. I've set up the synonym.